# "Чебураха -- мелкий гоблин..." Знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация, фонетика

Чебураха - мелкий гоблин (?)

Так глазищами моргал.

Он положен на мангал (?)

Мягкий, сочный, вкусный (?) Во', блин!

Какие знаки препинания нужно поставить на месте скобок?

Comment: Блины — в нетленку? Похвально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тире (закрывает пояснительную вставку "кто он такой"), двоеточие (внимание: посмотри, какой он), тире (- вот он какой!).

Возможны другие авторские интонации с соотв. знаками - особенно, если не сам Ч. был положен на мангал, а перед ним положили шашлык ("он"), о котором перед этим говорилось. Рифмы вполне сносные.

Comment: Чебураха - мелкий гоблин - так глазищами моргал. Он положен на мангал : мягкий, сочный, вкусный  -  вО, блин! Я правильно понял, Alex_ander?

Comment: Да. Возможно, вместо точки после "моргал" нужно что-то повыразительнее (многоточие или даже двоеточие - тогда после "мангала" тире, а после вкусного - многоточие, в порядке заминки перед "Во блин!").

Comment: Спасибо, Alex_ander !

Comment: Александр, если поставить тире получится вставка. А здесь приложение, вполне корректна запятая.